# Installing docker/compose-bin plugin on Google's Container Optimized OS

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, container-optimized-os

I am trying install the docker/compose-bin plugin on a Google Cloud VM with Container Optimized OS (https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose-bin/tags).

Has anybody achieved this?

I understand docker is running as a container and I think I have to install the plugin binary in the respective plugins folder inside the container. Am I in the right direction?

I am able to use the old docker-compose (https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose/tags) in a container using this script and alias:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=${1:-1.27.4}

echo "* Add an alias for docker-compose to the shell configuration file ..."
echo alias docker-compose="'"'docker run --rm \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v "$PWD:$PWD" \
    -w="$PWD" \
    docker/compose:'"${VERSION}"''"'" >> ~/.bashrc

echo "* Pull container image for docker-compose ..."
docker pull docker/compose:${VERSION}

echo "* Done"
echo "* To use docker-compose, run 'source ~/.bashrc' or simply re-login"
```

*taken from https://gist.github.com/kurokobo/25e41503eb060fee8d8bec1dd859eff3*

But I would really like to use the new plugin.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? `Has anybody achieved this?` is not a problem statement.

Comment: I am trying to install the docker/compose-bin plugin on a Google Cloud VM with Container Optimized OS. Don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hi @supercoco, the documents listed below may be of assistance 1) https://gist.github.com/kurokobo/25e41503eb060fee8d8bec1dd859eff3

 2) https://medium.com/@kyle.powers103/installing-docker-on-gcloud-vms-1479dd9dde30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writable and executable mounts [are](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security#filesystem):

- `/var/lib/{google,docker,toolbox}` (stateful)
- `/var/lib/cloud` (stateless, `tmpfs`, 2 MB)
- `/mnt/disks` (stateless, `tmpfs`, 256 KB)

`/var/lib/{google,docker,toolbox}` seems like the best option, and `/var/lib/google` is better then `/var/lib/docker` because it has `o+x` (I suppose `/var/lib/docker` lacks `o+x` for a reason):

```
$ sudo curl -sSL \
  https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.23.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 \
  -o /var/lib/google/docker-compose
$ sudo chmod o+x /var/lib/google/docker-compose
$ mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins
$ ln -sf /var/lib/google/docker-compose \
  ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
$ docker compose version
```

[the official installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/#install-the-plugin-manually) 
[where `docker` looks for plugins](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1534)

Alternatively one can use the [`docker` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker):

- using `alias`:

  `~/.profile`:

  ```bash
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
  ```

  `~/.bashrc`:

  ```bash
  alias docker-compose='docker run --rm docker compose'
  ```

  ```
  $ docker-compose version
  ```
- using a function:

  `~/.profile`:

  ```bash
  docker() {
      if [ "$1" = compose ]; then
          command docker run --rm docker "$@"
      else
          command docker "$@"
      fi
  }
  export -f docker
  ```

  ```bash
  $ docker compose version
  ```
- using a script:

  `/var/lib/google/bin/docker`:

  ```bash
  #!/bin/sh -eu
  if [ "$1" = compose ]; then
      /usr/bin/docker run --rm docker "$@"
  else
      /usr/bin/docker "$@"
  fi
  ```

  `~/.profile`:

  ```bash
  export PATH=/var/lib/google/bin:$PATH
  ```

  ```
  $ sudo chmod o+x /var/lib/google/bin/docker
  $ docker compose version
  ```

For the record, I also added the info to the [mentioned issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10463#issuecomment-1849586989).

Answer (score 2):

OK I was not in the right track. Docker compose is not a server plugin but a client plugin. So you just need it on your ~/.docker.

In COS (Container Optimized OS) the /var/lib/docker directory is writable and persistent so you can save the binaries there and create a symbolic link for every user that wants to use it.

These are the instructions that worked flawlessly:

```
DOCKER_CONFIG=${DOCKER_CONFIG:-$HOME/.docker}
CLI_PLUGINS=/var/lib/docker/cli-plugins
mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONFIG
sudo mkdir -p $CLI_PLUGINS
sudo curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.18.1/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o $CLI_PLUGINS/docker-compose
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/docker
ln -s $CLI_PLUGINS $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins
```

Thanks to https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10463

Other users on the same machine would have to run:

```
DOCKER_CONFIG=${DOCKER_CONFIG:-$HOME/.docker}
CLI_PLUGINS=/var/lib/docker/cli-plugins
mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONFIG
ln -s $CLI_PLUGINS $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins
```

Comment: almost flawlessly, this permission change won't persist ```sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/docker``` so you will have to add it to a cloud_init script or add specific users to a group in order to be able have permission to execute the binary file

Comment: I'd strongly suggest against making every file in `/var/lib/docker` executable, or even adding `o+x` to `/var/lib/docker`. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1149540/162443).